# List of vectors to list of lists

Tags: r, list, collections, purrr

I have a list structured this way:

```
x <- list(id = c("a", "b"),
          value = c(1,2),
          othervalue = c(3,4)
    )
```

I need to transform the list to this structure like this:

```
y <- list(a = list(value = 1, othervalue = 3),
          b = list(value = 2, othervalue = 4)
    )
```

How would you do this ?

---

Edit:

I stumbled upon a more advanced version of this problem:

Here there is some kind of nested list in the output.

```
x <-  list(id = c("a", "b", "a"), key = c("foo", "foo", "bar"), value = c(1, 2, 3))
```

to

```
y <- list(a = list(foo = 1, bar = 2), b  = list(foo = 3))
```

With the current answers, the result is:

```
$a
$a$key
[1] "foo"

$a$value
[1] 1


$b
$b$key
[1] "foo"

$b$value
[1] 2


$a
$a$key
[1] "bar"

$a$value
[1] 3
```

Comment: Thanks all for the answers, I stumbled on an advanced version of this problem. Any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `list` in `Map` with `do.call`.

```
z <- setNames(do.call(Map, c(list, x[-1])), x[[1]])

identical(z, y)
#[1] TRUE
```

The same but using pipes:

```
z <- c(list, x[-1]) |>
       do.call(what=Map) |>
       setNames(x[[1]])
```

---

Benchmark

```
x <- list(id = c("a", "b"), value = c(1,2), othervalue = c(3,4) )

bench::mark(purr = purrr::transpose(x[-1], .names = x[[1]]), #@Maël
            lapplySplit = lapply(split(as.data.frame(x)[-1], x$id), c), #@Allan Cameron
            Map = setNames(do.call(Map, c(list, x[-1])), x[[1]]) ) #@GKi

# expression       min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#  <bch:expr>  <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1 purr          2.51ms   2.64ms      372.    3.69MB     34.2   152    14
#2 lapplySplit 461.77µs 490.48µs     2018.  102.21KB     52.0   892    23
#3 Map          14.13µs   15.9µs    61557.    3.06KB     80.1  9987    13
```

Map is in this case about 30 times faster and allocates mutch less memory compared to lapplySplit the second.
And with the dataset from @s_baldur:

```
x <- list(id = c(letters, LETTERS), value = 1:52, othervalue = (1:52 + 100))
bench::mark(check=FALSE,
purr = purrr::transpose(x[-1], .names = x[[1]]), #@Maël
lapplySplit = lapply(split(as.data.frame(x)[-1], x$id), c), #@Allan Cameron
Map = setNames(do.call(Map, c(list, x[-1])), x[[1]]) ) #@GKi
#  expression       min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
#  <bch:expr>  <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1 purr           2.5ms   2.59ms      385.    3.69MB     33.9   159    14
#2 lapplySplit   2.43ms   2.51ms      391.  137.21KB     68.3   149    26
#3 Map          50.98µs  61.06µs    15717.    3.51KB     72.5  6506    30
```

---

For the updated question use maybe:

```
lapply(split(setNames(x$value, x$key), x$id), as.list)
```

But is there a need for a `list`? If not then use maybe:

```
split(setNames(x$value, x$key), x$id)
```

Comment: `transpose` is actually much faster on bigger data. see [@s_baldur's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76456185/13460602).

Comment: @Maël actually on my machine it's also much faster on the small data.  Using purrr 0.3.4

Comment: @Maël I have add a Benchmark with the other dataset, but the ranking is on my pc different. Maybe s_baldur is using another R version? I use 4.3.0. Or different libraries or hardware. Can you confirm s_baldur ranking or mine or have totally different?

Answer (score 4):

You could do

```r
lapply(split(as.data.frame(x)[-1], x$id), c)
#> $a
#> $a$value
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $a$othervalue
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> 
#> $b
#> $b$value
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $b$othervalue
#> [1] 4
```

Which is identical to `y`:

```r
identical(lapply(split(as.data.frame(x)[-1], x$id), c), y)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: This one might not respect the original order in `x$id`.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're mentioning `purrr` in your tags, you can use `purrr::transpose`:

```r
purrr::transpose(x[-1], .names = x[[1]])

# $a
# $a$value
# [1] 1
# 
# $a$othervalue
# [1] 3
# 
# 
# $b
# $b$value
# [1] 2
# 
# $b$othervalue
# [1] 4
```

Your second question looks like recursive splitting. To do so, a convenient option is `collapse::rsplit`:

```r
collapse::rsplit(data.frame(x), ~ id + key)

# $a
# $a$bar
# [1] 3
# 
# $a$foo
# [1] 1
# 
# 
# $b
# $b$foo
# [1] 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Keeping it simple:

```
foo <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x$id)
  y <- vector(mode = "list", length = n) |> setNames(x$id)
  for (i in seq_len(n)) y[[i]] <- list(value = x$value[i], othervalue = x$othervalue[i])
  y
}
```

Benchmark (with slightly bigger data):

```
x <- list(id = c(letters, LETTERS),
          value = 1:52,
          othervalue = (1:52 + 100)
    )
bench::mark(purr = purrr::transpose(x[-1], .names = x[[1]]),
            Map = setNames(do.call(Map, c(list, x[-1])), x[[1]]),
            loop = foo(x)) 

#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time                 
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>            
# 1 purr            5µs    5.8µs   137969.     1.2KB     27.6  9998     2     72.5ms
# 2 Map          32.3µs   34.7µs    27567.      464B     13.8  9995     5    362.6ms
# 3 loop         16.5µs   17.5µs    52962.      464B     15.9  9997     3    188.8ms
```

Answer (score 2):

## Update

Regarding the update in the question, you can try `split` + `lapply`

```
lapply(split(list2DF(x[-1]), x[[1]]), \(v) with(v, split(value, key)))
```

or we can use `aggregate` + `Map`

```
with(
    aggregate(x[-1], x[1], as.list),
    setNames(Map(setNames, value, key), id)
)
```

which gives

```
$a
$a$bar
[1] 3

$a$foo
[1] 1


$b
$b$foo
[1] 2
```

---

## For Previous Question

You can try

```
list2DF(x[-1]) %>%
    split(1:nrow(.)) %>%
    setNames(x[[1]]) %>%
    lapply(c)
```

which gives

```
$a
$a$value
[1] 1

$a$othervalue
[1] 3


$b
$b$value
[1] 2

$b$othervalue
[1] 4
```